# Unable to locate renderkit instance for render-kit-id oracle.adf.rich

Tags: jboss, wildfly, oracle-adf

I am trying to execute my oracle adf application(ADF 12) on Wildfly 12. And I got this error message:

`SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-1) Unable to locate renderkit instance for render-kit-id oracle.adf.rich.  Using HTML_BASIC instead.`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you doing?
<application>
       <default-render-kit-id> the oracle one here</default-render-kit-id>
   </application>

Comment: Did you install adf runtime on your Wildfly server? I don't think it's there by default.

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior Yes,I did it. I put it in faces-config.xml file.

Comment: @Cedric How to install adf runtime on Wildfly? I just export adf libraries in widlfly modules. Is that the right way?